# XCode project version bump, is there automated way?

Tags: xcode, versioning, xcodebuild

*I would like to know if there are any automated ways to bump up the version number of an xcode project?*

I was using Jeweller with Ruby which has really nice command line option to bump up the version number on a project. The option were major, minor, or patch. X.X.X

Is there any similar (semi-)automated way to bump a version number in xcode? The only way I know is to the manually edit the main plist. Would be great if anything recorded builds or integrated with version control even.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use `agvtool` to do this.